# Multiple inheritance and Java

Tags: java, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Multiple inheritance is not supported in Java (as of yet, but will likely stay this way).

But, what about the `Object` class? Say you have an object `A` that inherits from the `Object` class. Now, you create a class `B` that inherits from the `A` class. But, with every class inheriting the `Object` class, isn't `B` exhibiting multiple inheritance by both inheriting from `Object` and `A`?

Is it that Java *knows* it will always have objects inheriting from the `Object` class and therefore can support it easily? Otherwise, if everyone was inheriting from multiple classes all willy-nilly, Oracle would have to have to implement a lot more support.

Or, is it that rather than inheriting from both `Object` and `A`, `B` is inheriting only from `A` which *contains* the inheritance from `Object` all wrapped in one object?

Comment: The sentence in the bottom is somewhat the answer to your question.

Comment: Java 8 added kind-of multiple inheritance via `default` methods in interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is based on a misunderstanding.

> But, what about the Object class? Say you have an object A that inherits from the Object class. Now, you create a class B that inherits from the A class. But, with every class inheriting the Object class, isn't B exhibiting multiple inheritance by both inheriting from Object and A?

The misunderstanding is here - *"with every class inheriting the Object class"*

In fact, an class only (implicitly) extends `Object` if it does not explicitly `extend` another class.

`Object` is the ultimate superclass of every class, but it is not a direct superclass of every class.  The Java class hierarchy is a tree, with `Object` at the top.

Comment: Thanks! A few of us were studying for a final and we kinda hit a roadblock when we realized the (now defunct realization) that every class inherits the object class.